# Turning NextJS website to desktop app: Electron, React-Native or React-Desktop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, electron

I've just learnt ReactJS and am currently using it develop an application with NextJS. I plan to make it available as a desktop application, too.

I've come across Electron, React-Native and React-Desktop, but I am uncertain which would be the best choice. I would prefer a solution which allows me to use most of the code I've already written (so React-Native probably isn't the best choice?)

Also: Does the use of NextJS make it harder to turn it to a desktop application (since there aren't really URL paths in a desktop app)? Is it possible to somehow automatically "convert" for example Link components, so they work in a Desktop app? Or are NextJS features only usable when the code runs in a browser (which would mean, that I may use my React Components, but not the NextJS site structure)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can use  `create-react-app`  over `nextjs`. NextJs is designed to run on the server mostly .

Answer (score 0):

You should try https://github.com/saltyshiomix/create-nextron-app

## `basic-javascript` example

$ npx create-nextron-app my-app